# How to do a cycling value javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am currently working on a Js animation.

Let me explain :

I have several objects which have each Y position `this.y`. I want to make them moving up like this `this.y -= 0.1` with a delay on each.

Problem : I want to change the direction to down when the object has moved up to 10px from its original position (with this code `this.y += 0.1`). When it moved -10px from its original pos, change the direction to up (`this.y -= 0.1`).

It is a sort of cycling value. Any idea ? I thought to increment an another variable, something like this :

```
this.incr = 0;
this.incr += 0.1;

if(this.incr == 1){
  this.y += 0.1;
}

else if(this.incr == -1){
  this.y -= 0.1;
}
```

I know it is not the good way but I can not find the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Record a `delta` value in your object and use it to update the value on each call. If you hit the limit, change the value of delta.

```
myObject.update = function () {
    this.value += this.delta
    // if `this.value` reaches 1, the update function should subtract
    // 0.1 on each subsequent call, so set `this.delta` to -0.1
    if (this.value === 1)
        this.delta = -0.1
    // likewise, if `this.value` reaches -1, then the update function
    // should add 0.1 on each call, so set `this.delta` to 0.1
    else if (this.value === -1)
        this.delta = +0.1 
}
```

Of course, this is an abstraction of what you're after. You're going to need to figure out how to translate `this.value += this.delta` (ie., how the object should update) and when to switch the value of `this.delta` into your application.